# How to ignore grep backreferences from the file?

Tags: grep

I've the following two files:

```
$ cat in1.lst 
foo.pdf
bar.pdf
$ cat in2.lst 
foo.pdf
bar\355xyz.pdf
```

The following `grep` command works for the first, but not for the second:

```
$ grep -f in1.lst /dev/null
$ grep -f in2.lst /dev/null 
grep: invalid backreference number
```

In the real scenario I've a file with long list of URLs and some of them have `\xxx` strings. I'd like to run `grep` and ignore any special meaning for backreferences.

How can I ignore backreferences special meaning when loading the file via `-f` parameter?

---

Extra info:

```
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
$ type grep
grep is aliased to `grep --color=auto'
```

Comment: Your question is misleading... it isn't about ignoring backreferences (which is a term used in a regex context - so e.g. ignore the backreferences but treat everything else as a regex) but actually about grepping for literal strings, IOW _how to grep for fixed strings_ (so not a regex context).

Comment: @don_crissti I've file with list of URLs, but when running the `grep` command, it is basically complaining about *invalid backreference number* for unknown reasons, so I guess the question is about ignoring backreference numbers (whatever it may be). Otherwise the `grep` error it-self is misleading.

Comment: C'mon man, it's quite obvious why `grep` is complaining about an invalid backreference number...

Comment: I'm not using any regex parameters, so shouldn't grep by default treat input files as fixed strings for performance reasons? I didn't know about this problem and *backreference numbers* till I debugged my file with 10k of lines to find few lines which were causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `-F`/`--fixed-strings` parameter should be used which can interpret patterns as a set of fixed strings (so it forces `grep` to behave as `fgrep`). See: `man grep`.

So:

```
grep -F -f in2.lst /dev/null
```

or:

```
fgrep -f in2.lst /dev/null
```